# Prevent eager loading from including children of included entities (stop self-referencing loop)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two entities that have a many-to-many relationship.  When I eager load one entity using Include() it loads the children and ALSO includes the children of the children.  I do not want the grandchildren.

I turned off lazy loading: LazyLoadingEnabled = false; and am ignoring self referencing loops:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
    .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling
    .Ignore;
```

To better explain things:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the [IUnitOfWork pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) (see Creating a Generic Repository) so load the entities thus:

```
return unitOfWork.ARepository.Get(a => a.Id == Id, null, "Bs");
```

I get back JSON that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Bs": [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "As": [
              {
                "Id": 2,
                "Bs": [

          ...

  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Bs": [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "As": [
              {
                "Id": 1,
                "Bs": [

         ...
```

Passing the self-referenced entities seems really wasteful.  Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I added the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute to the As property in class B.

```
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]    
    public ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

I believe it is safe to do this because I will not reference Class A through B.  That relationship is present for EF Code First.

To use [JsonIgnore] install it using Nuget (https://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```